# Is there way to provide custom error message for validation fail in openAPI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi-generator, openapi-3-0

I have following field definition:

```
MyField:
  description: blablabla
  type: integer
  default: 1
  minimum: 1
  exclusiveMinimum: false
```

In case if I provide -1 value I receive standard error like

```
 Validation failed for argument [1] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List...]; default message [must be greater than or equal to 1]]
```

Is there way to customize this error message ?

Comment: I wonder who is downvoting all the questions without giving any reason in the comment?

Comment: Do you mean to get rid of the first part of the error message and get only "must be greater than or equal to 1"? Or do you want to change the text of the last part?

Comment: Custom validation can be implemented with `x-constraints` property, an annotation and a class implementing `ConstraintValidator` interface.

Comment: @Mar-Z I would like to fuly replace error mesasge but if there are options to replace it partialy - it is also ok

Comment: Please check this tutorial. At the moment I personally don't have any relevant code examples. https://www.baeldung.com/java-swagger-custom-validation